# How to make a Discord.py bot change another user's nickname?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a Discord.py bot to have this mini-game where there is a race, and who ever wins, gets to change anyone's nicknames in the server. I have completed most of the code, but I am stuck on how to change another user's nickname. I am able to obtain the requested username, but am unable to change that specific username since it is in a string. I did go through the docs, but those only seemed to show how to change the nickname of the user that requested it. How would I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Use `discord.Member.edit(name='')`

Comment: Please provide more details as to how your code is working. How are you determining which member to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like "*await member.edit(nick=nickname)*"

```
@bot.command()
async def nick(ctx,member=discord.Member,*,nickname):
    await member.edit(nick=nickname)
```